# Footer Not Expanding Properly in HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, web-deployment

so I created a website and I want to expand my footer because right now it looks like this:
[image]

It should cover the whole website and I tried increasing the width, but it didnt work.

This is the HTML/CSS of the footer:

```css
#footer {
  background: #f7f8f9;
  color: #45505b;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

#footer h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

#footer p {
  font-size: 15;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

#footer .social-links {
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

#footer .social-links a {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #0563bb;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin-right: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#footer .social-links a:hover {
  background: #0678e3;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#footer .copyright {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#footer .credits {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
 <footer id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>My name</h3>
      <p></p>
      <div class="social-links">
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kaustubh-prabhakar/" class="linkedin"><i class="bx bxl-linkedin"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href=href="https://github.com/SantaKaus" class="github"><i class="bx bxl-github"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.instagram.com/santa_kaus/" class="instagram"><i class="bx bxl-instagram"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
        &copy; <strong><span>my name</span></strong> 2021
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer><!-- End Footer -->
```

I got the whole footer code from another source, and I tried copying and pasting the code exactly it is, but for some reason I cannot get it to expand more idk why. Can you guys please help?

Comment: Hmmm. Seems to work for me when I run the code snippet. Could you edit your answer to be more specific about your problem, and also specify your browser?

Comment: I am using chrome, and yeah for some reason the above code outputs the expected output I want, but when I copy and paste it into my project, I am getting the output that I sent in the picture above.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GMEZJ2NU9BAL. What program/text editor/other are you using? Are you viewing it locally through a downloaded HTML file, or through an online text editor?

Comment: through repl.it but what I think the issue is maybe some parts are overriding each other? Because I have multiple css files in my main project

Comment: what part of the css is causing it not to expand like is it the issue with .footer?

Comment: So far, it just looks like the .footer is placed inline for some reason. Would it be possible to share the repl?

Comment: What should I change it to?

Comment: I can't say for sure without looking at other parts of your code. But, try adding a `display:block!important` to the footer's css.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Footer not enlarging/expanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65614312/footer-not-enlarging-expanding)

Comment: It works for me, even in the repl.